# Is it possible to automate installion using Ruby or Watir?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Currently we are installing our setup(.exe file) on daily basis for testing purpose.I want to automate my installation using Ruby or Watir.Is it possible to automate? Please help me how to perform and give your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There are many libraries available for Ruby.  Watir itself is constrained to the web browser.  Although it does have some technology it's built on top of that should allow Windows environment control.  Some of the libraries you can try are [Win32-autogui](http://www.gearheadforhire.com/articles/ruby/win32-autogui/using-ruby-to-drive-windows-applications), [RAutomation](http://itreallymatters.net/post/2352350743/automating-windows-and-their-controls-with-ruby#.VFypJIVBgtk), and [windows-pr](http://blog.likewise.org/2012/04/pure-ruby-example-of-calling-functions/) to name a few.

Comment: Hi 6ft Dan thanks for the help.I tried the libraries which you have given.But there is no luck.Using RAutomation(http://itreallymatters.net/post/2352350743/automating-windows-and-their-controls-with-ruby#.VF5CnWfthCG) i tried to install Firefox browser.It recognize the "Next >" button,but unable to click as it displays Timeout error.Do we have any gems to try?Please help

Comment: The RAutomation that's built into Watir I never had any luck with.  I would stick with the other libraries first.  I haven't used a stand alone RAutomation.

Comment: You know if you're making the executable, you could have built in command line options for everything.  Then you don't need to manipulate the Windows GUI.  Also there's keyboard emulation.  You can get around any system without a mouse.  Might be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing for testing purposes, you can use [autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). It will run your installer, and you can handle some unexpected (though anticipated) errors. I wouldn't use autoit for testing, just for setting up to test.